# ios to javascript convert

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cordova

I am using the sample SensorTag application code in our application and our application is cordova based. Here I have one problem. In SensorTag application they are using the following line of code. Can you please tell what is it mean and How to convert that to JavaScript from the iOS code

```
char scratchVal[data.length];
int16_t objTemp;
int16_t ambTemp;
[data getBytes:&scratchVal length:data.length];
int16_t objTemp = (scratchVal[0] & 0xff)| ((scratchVal[1] << 8) & 0xff00);
int16_t ambTemp = ((scratchVal[2] & 0xff)| ((scratchVal[3] << 8) & 0xff00));
```

Here the data is NSData type and from the which is data from the BLE device.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Guys, can you help me out please. I stuck with this

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I got that Android code & found the conversion how Ti doing

Comment: Good to hear. I remember this question, but I can't seem to see my reply in the comments though?